# Show files to be patched on .diff file and determine if they are patched or not

Tags: patch-management, diff

Having a `.diff` patch file, I'm trying to take actions in a shell script depending on if files listed in `.diff` file are: 1) already patched, 2) not patched, 3) not patchable.

I found no way on GNU Patch to show this information in a non-interactive basis.

Also would be useful knowing which files are to be patched without patching them. This seem to be easier filtering the `.diff` file but would be great if GNU Patch had these features.

Some suggestion on this?

Comment: Have you tried `--dry-run`?

Comment: Yes @MichaelHampton. Without `-t` and `-f` it may be interactive (when patch is already applied). The closest solution would be executing `--dry-run -fNs` and `--dry-run -fRs`. If both exits with exit code 1 we have an error (not patchable); if `-fNs` exits with 0 means that files are to be patched, and if `-fRs` exits with code 0 means that files are already patched.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution.

To show the list of files to be processed: `lsdiff` from patchutils.

To determine the patch status of the tree I wrote this sh function:

```
checkpatch(){
 local normal reverso file

 file="$1"

 patch -p1 --dry-run -fNs < "$file" &>/dev/null && normal=0 || normal=1
 patch -p1 --dry-run -fRs < "$file" &>/dev/null && reverso=0 || reverso=1

 if [ "$normal" == "1" ] && [ "$reverso" == "1" ]; then
    echo Error ; return 2
 else
    if [ "$normal" == "0" ]; then
       echo Not patched ; return 1
    else
       echo Patched ; return 0
    fi
 fi
}
```

Use `checkpatch` followed with a `.diff` file and it will say whether the tree is patched or not.